# Efficient dynamic Jackson configuration using Spring GET Parameters

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I have Spring Boot set up to serve JSON.

I'd like to build a feature where user can provide white-listed get parameters that are passed to Jackson ObjectMapper

Examples:

```
json?indent_output=true
json?write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

However I can't find a way to do this without creating an instance of ObjectMapper in each Spring MVC Controller method, configuring it according to get parameters and then returning pure strings.

Is there a way to do this with reusing just one ObjectMapper?

Comment: ObjectMapper is only thread-safe _after_ configuration, so it cannot be reused directly in your case; what you can do, is getting fresh ObjectWriter instances with static factory calls to ObjectMapper methods.

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas how I would inject get parameters inside the ObjectMapper methods in a thread-safe way?

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem? I have a pretty much similar situation where I need to retrieve in body response only those fields included in the url

Comment: Ended up not to implement the feature. Maybe it could be done trough light-weight ObjectWriters.